# How exactly do you use a module in Ocaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I want to use the [Stack module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stack.html).

From my understanding, it is part of the stdlib library. I have run the command `ocamlbuild -package stdlib <myfile>.native` as suggested from another post. 
I have also added `open Stdlib.Stack` at the top of my file to load the module.

I still get the error `Error: Unbound value stack`

Comment: It would help to get more useful answers if you showed the code where the error occurs.

Comment: Impossible to know without seeing the code that fails if this would help, but I'd try capitalising `stack` ↦ `Stack`

Comment: Thank you. It was the lack of capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module names in OCaml are capitalized. Your error message suggests you're using the name `stack`. This is not a module name, and there is no name `stack` that appears in the `Stack` module.

It is hard to say more without seeing your code.

Here is some code that manipulates a stack:

```
# let mystack = Stack.create ();;
val mystack : '_weak1 Stack.t = <abstr>
# Stack.push "greetings" mystack;;
- : unit = ()
# Stack.length mystack;;
- : int = 1
# Stack.pop mystack;;
- : string = "greetings"
```